# angualr6 : iframe src attribute updating but pdf not showing some times

Tags: angular, iframe, blob

Below is the code I have written, Pdf file shows once and not shows once (failed to load pdf). I replaced with iFrame as well, same scenario. Some times shows pdf some times not. Can anybody help me out.

My html element:

```
       <embed [src]="pdf.pdfSource | safe" type="application/pdf">
```

My Ts Code:

```
  var blob = new Blob([response.collection], {
        type: 'application/pdf'
      });
      var url = URL.createObjectURL(response);
      self.pdf.pdfSource = url;
```

I created a safe pipe like below

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation, ViewChild, ElementRef, PipeTransform, Pipe, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
   import { DomSanitizer } from "@angular/platform-browser";

   @Pipe({ name: 'safe' })
       export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
          constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }
            transform(url) {        
              return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
            }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to create a custom component to handle such requirement:

Create a object-embed `component` and pass the source url and type to it as `input` attributes. This would update every time there is a change in the input values to component.

Ex:

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
    selector: 'object-embed',
    template: `<div [innerHTML]="safeHtml"></div>`,
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ObjectEmbedComponent implements OnChanges {
    @Input() srcUrl: string;
    @Input() embedType: string;
    public safeHtml: SafeHtml;

    ngOnChanges() {

       let html = '';
       if(this.embedType ==='application/pdf'){
           html = '<embed src="${this.srcUrl} type="${this.embedType}">'
       }
       this.safeHtml = this.getSafeHtml(html);
   }


     getSafeHtml(html: string) {
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
     }

}
```

And use this component:

```
<object-embed [embedType]="pdf" [srcUrl]="document-url-here"/>
```

Now these values can be passed using a object/variable defined in parent component or directly. if you have a object `docDetails` with these value, you can use it like this (assuming it has properties `docType` and `docUrl`:

```
<object-embed [embedType]="docDetails.docType" [srcUrl]="docDetails.docUrl"/>
```

Comment: Do I need to create Input variables for embedType  and srcUrl at parent component which is holding <object-embed [embedType]="pdf" [srcUrl]="document-url-here"/>

Comment: No, the `Input` is already defined in `object-embed `, You just need to make sure that Parent component uses `object-embed` and provides it with necessary data which is srcUrl and type of media. Ex: `<object-embed [embedType]="application/pdf" [srcUrl]="document-url-here"/>`

Comment: you can also have the same component to use `<iframe src="${this.srcUrl}"...` for html

Comment: embed as ell as obejct not workingOnChanges() {
    
    let html = '';

    html = '<embed src="' + this.srcUrl + '" type="application/pdf" >';     No Use.

Comment: some times comes , some times pdf wont come

Comment: @Abhi, Would you be able to share a working code in https://stackblitz.com, I can take a look and help